# How do I find corner of reactangle if the origin X is Positive and Z is Negative?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry

I have a 3D world and have plane coordinates like this.
[Coord x, -y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nDKS.png)
. How do I determine the (x,y) coordinates of each corner. I've observed and take some research that I got this formula :
[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvcGk.png)
However this didn't get the result I wanted.

```
function rotating(cx, cy, x, y, angle) {
const radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
const cos = Math.cos(radians);
const sin = Math.sin(radians);
const newX = (x - cx) * cos - (y - cy) * sin + cx;
const newY = (y - cy) * cos + (x - cx) * sin + cy;
return [newX, newY];
}
const P1 = rotating(10, -10, 8, -12, 90);
```

Hope the result will be (8, -8) but got (12, -12)

Comment: If you need further explanation from my answer, you can just ask :)

Comment: @Sandsten Thanks for your explaination. If the result same, how do I converting angle 90degree from 3D toolkit to be anticlockwise? by multiply -1 ? eg. angle *-1 ? Is this the right way ?

Comment: Yes, you just have to rotate by -90 degrees instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result will be (12,-12) since your y-axis is inverted, hence positive rotation will be clockwise from this perspective. Positive rotation in 2D is always from positive x-axis to positive y-axis.
The Wikipedia article on rotation matrices explains this quite well https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Here's a modified version of your image. I moved the red square to match your y-labels.

[image]

I had some spare time and converted your function to use matrix multiplication instead, with the library math.js. Using matrix operations makes it easier to do the same with multiple coordinates. You can modify this function to use other transformation matrices for which ever effect you need. Here are some examples https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Matrix operations</title>
    <!-- math.js library for matrix operations -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/9.4.3/math.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>

        function localRotation(x, y, xc, yc, angle) {
            // Create a matrix where each row is a dimension
            // First row is x, second is y, and last is z (filled with ones to allow for translation with matrix multiplication)
            var coordinates = math.matrix([
                x, // x values
                y, // y values
                math.ones(x.length) // "Homogenous coordinates addition"
            ]);

            // Matrix for rotating
            const radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
            const rotate = math.matrix([
                [Math.cos(radians), -Math.sin(radians), 0],
                [Math.sin(radians), Math.cos(radians),  0],
                [0,                 0,                  1]
            ]);

            // Matrix for translating the square to the origin
            const translateToOrigin = math.matrix([
                [1, 0, -xc],
                [0, 1, -yc],
                [0, 0,   1],
            ]);      

            // Matrix for translating the square back to its original position
            const translateToOriginalPos = math.matrix([
                [1, 0, xc],
                [0, 1, yc],
                [0, 0,  1],
            ]);  

            // Combine all transformations into one matrix
            // The operations are in order from left to right!
            // First translate square to origin, then rotate, then translate back to original position
            const allTransformations = math.multiply(translateToOriginalPos, rotate, translateToOrigin);

            // Apply the transformation matrix
            coordinates = math.multiply(allTransformations, coordinates);
            // Here you should also divide each coordinate by the last row, but I didn't find an elegant way of doing it
            // It's not necessary, I think, when you only translate and rotate

            // Extract the x and y coordinates and return them
            const xCoordinates = coordinates._data[0];
            const yCoordinates = coordinates._data[1];
            return [xCoordinates, yCoordinates];
        }

        const squareVerticesXPos = [  8,  12, 12,  8]; // x coordinates
        const squareVerticesYPos = [-12, -12, -8, -8]; // y coordinates
        const squareOriginX = 10; // x, y, z (homogenous coordinate)
        const squareOriginY = -10; // x, y, z (homogenous coordinate)
        const angle = 90;

        const newCoordinates = localRotation(squareVerticesXPos, squareVerticesYPos, squareOriginX, squareOriginY, angle);
        
        console.log("Starting coordinates (x,y)");
        console.log(math.transpose([squareVerticesXPos, squareVerticesYPos]));
        
        console.log("Coordinates (x,y) after transforming");
        console.log(math.transpose(newCoordinates));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```